# Show that $\operatorname{Im}(z\bar z)=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

The first part of the question asked 'let $z=re^{iθ}$ be a complex number, show that $\bar z=re^{-iθ}$' which I have shown by using Euler's formula, however, I am stuck with the next part of the question which asks, 'Hence show that $\operatorname{Im}(z\bar z)=0$'.

I assumed it meant that I have to multiply the imaginary parts of z but I don't know how to get to 0 from doing that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by computing $z\overline{z}$.

Comment: "I have to multiply the imaginary parts of z" sounds wrong
$\operatorname{Im}(z\bar z)=0$
is asking you to multiply $z$ and $\bar z$  and then take the imaginary component of the product.  It is not asking to the product of the two imaginary components.

Answer (score 4):

$z\overline z=re^{i\theta}re^{-i\theta}=r^2$, which is a real number. Therefore, its imaginary part is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=a+bi$, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$ then $z\overline{z}=(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$.

$Im(a^2+b^2)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Compute $z\overline z$:\begin{align}z\overline z&=re^{i\theta}re^{-i\theta}\\
&=r^2e^{((i\theta) +(-i\theta))}\\
&=r^2e^0\\
&=r^2\end{align}

Now we see that $r^2$ is real, and thus $$\text{Im}(z\overline z)=0$$